# eclipse rcp e4: how to highlight the selected tab in part stack?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

What I have now (notice there is no highlight):

[image]

What I want (highlight the currently active part):

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These colors are controlled by your CSS.

Assuming you are using the usual e4 tab renderer the selected tab color can be set with:

```css
.MPartStack.active {
     swt-selected-tabs-background: #E5EDFC #99BAF3 100%;
}
```

By the 'usual tab renderer' I mean:

```css
.MPartStack {
    swt-tab-renderer: url('bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering');
}
```

Update:

Inactive tab colors are controlled by the `swt-unselected-tabs-color` value.

Comment: The first code gives me the right behaviour when a tab gets activated, but the color does not go back when the tab is deactivated.

Comment: Check you have an `swt-unselected-tabs-color` color specified

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. What I meant was when I select a tab in part stack A, that tab becomes highlighted as expected. But then I select another tab in another part stack B, but the previous one (in part stack A) does not go back.

Comment: Specify a different 'swt-selected-tabs-background' for '.MPartStack' (as well as the '.MPartStack.active' value).